# VBA transpose multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am currently working on a big set of data downloaded from Morningstar Direct. I need help with a macro that can change the exported document from horizontal to vertical. I have tried all the functions in excel without any luck, so i think i need a macro for this operation.

For example:

From:

```
Data1-2000    Data1-2001   Data1-2002 ... Data1-2016   Data2-2000   Data2-2001 and so on
```

To:

```
Data1-2000  
Data1-2001  
   ...  
Data1-2016  
Data2-2000  
Data2-2001  
     ...
```

Every datavariable goes from 2000 to 2016. We have more then 500 tickers that need the same transformation. Is there any VBA code that can do this for me? It will save my life (at least my Easter)!

**Addedum from OP's answer post:

I have made this macro:

```
Sub Flip()
'
' Flip Macro
'
    Sheets("S&P 500 Constituents").Select
    Range("I2:X2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("S&P 500 Constituents").Select
    Range("AB2:AQ2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("S&P 500 Constituents").Select
    Range("AR2:BG2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("S&P 500 Constituents").Select
    Range("BH2:BW2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("S&P 500 Constituents").Select
    Range("BX2:CM2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

As you can see everything is taken from row 2 in my S&P500 sheet, and then transposed into sheet1.

How can i make this macro repeat the same operation on row 3, 4, 5 ... 518?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
=INDEX($1:$1, 1, ROW(1:1))
```

[image: index_dumbass]

**Addendum: [VBA strip & transpose](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/VBA%20transpose%20multiple%20times.xlsb)**

Dumping the values from the S&P 500 Constituents worksheet into a two-dimensioned variant array and processing the reorientation in-memory to a second array would be the most expedient method.

```
Sub Flip()
' Flip Macro
    Dim v As Long, val As Variant, vals As Variant
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, stp As Long

    stp = 16
    ReDim val(1 To stp, 1 To 1)

    With Worksheets("S&P 500 Constituents")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "CM").End(xlUp))
            vals = .Value2
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For a = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            For b = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2) - stp Step stp
                For v = 1 To stp
                    val(v, 1) = vals(a, b - ((b > 1) * 3) + (v - 1))
                Next v
                .Cells(2, "D").Offset((a - 1) * stp, Int(b / stp)).Resize(stp, 1) = val
            Next b
        Next a

    End With

End Sub
```

I've intentionally avoided the use of the native [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) as it has limitations for size that are more suited to an .xls than an .xlsx. The maths that supply the looped reorientation have been derived from your sample code's first row.